# (jquery) how to get 4 animations runing one by one in a simple way...?

Tags: jquery, function, animation, for-loop

I was looking all day for an answer for this question... 
I want 4 div's to `fadeTo(0)` and then `fadeTo(1)` one by one.
I just started learning jquery, so I don't want to use all the complicated ways to do this.
this is my code:

```
for(var i=0;i<11;i++)
            {
                $(function () { $("#red").fadeTo("medium", 0); $("#red").fadeTo("medium", 1); })
                $(function () { $("#blue").fadeTo("medium", 0); $("#blue").fadeTo("medium", 1); })
                $(function () { $("#yellow").fadeTo("medium", 0); $("#yellow").fadeTo("medium", 1); })
                $(function () { $("#green").fadeTo("medium", 0); $("#green").fadeTo("medium", 1); })
            }})
```

can someone help me ?

---

thank you all for helping me ! but i just figured i need another thing...
i need the 4 div's to do this:
`#red`, needs to `fadeout` and then as he `fadesin`, the next `div` needs to start `fadeout`... 
can someone please help me with that?... again?

Comment: to clarify do you want `#red` to fade out and in followed by `#blue`, followed by `#yellow`?

Comment: zzzzBov- yes, i forgot that... just edited the question

Comment: FiLeVeR10- the loop is for doing the animation effect again and again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the animations to happen in a queued fashion where `#red` fades, followed by `#blue`, followed by `#yellow`, followed by `#green`, then I recommend making use of jQuery's [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) function:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).queue(function (n) {
        $('#red').fadeTo('medium', 0).fadeTo('medium', 1, n);
    }).queue(function (n) {
        $('#blue').fadeTo('medium', 0).fadeTo('medium', 1, n);
    }).queue(function (n) {
        $('#yellow').fadeTo('medium', 0).fadeTo('medium', 1, n);
    }).queue(function (n) {
        $('#green').fadeTo('medium', 0).fadeTo('medium', 1, n);
    });
});
```

---

In a real project I'd be much more inclined to use something along the lines of:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('[data-fader]').each(function () {
        var $this,
            data;
        $this = $(this);
        data = $this.data('fader');
        $(window).queue(function (n) {
            $this.fadeTo(data.outDuration, 0).fadeTo(data.inDuration, 1, n);
        });
    });
});
```

Which would go along with code such as:

```
<div data-fader='{"outDuration": 400,"inDuration": 400}'>lorem ipsum...</div>
<div data-fader='{"outDuration": 400,"inDuration": 400}'>...</div>
<div data-fader='{"outDuration": 400,"inDuration": 400}'>...</div>
<div data-fader='{"outDuration": 400,"inDuration": 400}'>...</div>
```

This would allow the settings to be configured from the HTML without needing to update the JS later. I'd also recommend adding good defaults via [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), and some options on animation.

Comment: @FiLeVeR10, I'm not sure I follow. You can easily reorder and insert new steps into the queue. These callback functions are all part of a single queue attached to the window object.

Comment: @FiLeVeR10, I think more importantly, this sort of structure is helpful when the animations and timings change on a per-element basis, although for that I'd typically use `[data-*]` attributes to store those configurable options.

Comment: @FiLeVeR10, I've updated my answer with the more complex, non-repetitive code that I'd be more likely to use.

Answer (score 0):

**this might be easier**

jQuery

```
$('.fad').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i*2000).fadeTo(1000,0).fadeTo(1000,1);      
});
```

I added a class of `fad` on each of the items, to select them all with one selector.

You need to specify the duration, so you can clear it with a delay.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/d8rpc/

**edit:** You could also replace `$('.fad')` with `$('#red,#blue,#yellow,#green')` if you don't want to add a class. I added it so they can be thought of as one unit instead of 4 separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cool jQuery deferred feature http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7e4rk/

```
function blink(what) {
    return function() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred(); //deferred object
        what = $("#" + what); //div we need to blink
        what.fadeOut("slow", function(){
            what.fadeIn("slow", function(){dfd.resolve()})
        });

        return dfd.promise(); //promise for chaining
    }
};

blink("red")().then(blink("blue")).then(blink("yellow")).then(blink("green"))
```

Comment: Well, at least this code is more maintainable than `i*2000`. What if the order of animation is not the same as the order of animated elements inside DOM? :)

Comment: I'm quite sure this `$('#red,#blue,#yellow,#green')` wont help. Elements returned by a selector got to be sorted in order it appears inside DOM.

Comment: Okay. What about different timings? slow, fast, slow, slow :)